# MPI_Comm_create_group substitue in old versions of OpenMPI(1.6)

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, communicator

I am trying to create a communicator over a group of ranks. In the newer versions of OpenMPI (after 1.7) this can be done using `MPI_Comm_create_group`.
Is there a method to do this same task in OpenMPI before 1.6?

Note: I cannot use `MPI_Comm_create` as all the ranks may not be able to call the function `MPI_Comm_Create`.

Comment: MPI and OpenMPI is not the same. The version numbers you are referring to is the OpenMPI library version, not the MPI standard version.

Comment: I am aware of this.(And this does not help me solve my problem).

Comment: This is not to solve your problem. This is to write a correct question.

Comment: There is no substitute for `MPI_Comm_create_group` when not all ranks are able to make the call. In MPI before 3.0 all communicator constructors are globally collective.